# form_for 'file_field' not showing file chosen in edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `file_field` and it is working fine on creation - file is getting saved. But when I'm doing edit of the same record `no file chosen` is coming.

I have created partial form which I am using in new and edit actions. When I am clicking on edit option of a record all other fields are coming pre-selected but file is not coming.

```
# edit.html.erb
<h3>Order Detail</h3>
<div id="field">
  <div id="field0">
    <%= render 'form', order_detail: @order_detail %>
  </div>
</div>   

# _form.html.erb
<%= form_for @order_detail do |f| %> 
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="action_id">Delivery Date</label>  
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <%=f.text_field :delivery_date, "data-provide" => 'datepicker', class: 'form-control input-md datepicker',id: 'selectDate2',placeholder: "Delivery date(yyyy-mm-dd)" ,required: true%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="action_id">Pdf File</label>  
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <%=f.file_field :pdf_file, class: 'form-control input-md' ,required: true%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Submit",class:"btn btn-success" ,remote: true%>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

I am expecting file chosen should come but it's not coming as it is stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that file through a link parallel to your file field.
File field itself cannot show the stored file in edit mode.

```
<% if !f.object.new_record? && f.object.photo.present? %> 
  <%= image_tag :photo.url(:small) %> 
<% else %> 
  <%=f.file_field :photo, class: 'form-control input-md' ,required: true%> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have done like this <%=f.file_field :pdf_file, class: 'form-control input-md' ,required: true%><%= f.object&.pdf_file&.file&.filename %>......Now 'no file chosen' and file name both are coming.When I click on submit button it ask to select file.

Comment: Yes it is the expected behaviour here.
You should not add your <%= f.object&.pdf_file&.file&.filename %> inside file field. you should add a link here in same level to file field to link you file.

If someone again selects the different file, just delete the previous one and add the new one.

Comment: Then how should I manage this case as it is asking to select file.

Comment: Do you want the file field to be not able to select the file in edit mode?

Let the user select the new file in edit mode of the form. If the file is changed then update your file.

Comment: I want the normal behaviour if file is available then it should be there and one wants to change they can click on 'choose file' to select other one.

Comment: The approach that I follow here is - 
When its a new record just show the file field.
When its not a new record and image is available then show the image_tag.

Something like - 
```
<% if !f.object.new_record? && f.object.photo.present? %>
    <%= image_tag :photo.url(:small) %>
  <% else %>
    <%=f.file_field :photo, class: 'form-control input-md' ,required: true%>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: @AshishGarg please, edit your answer and add code from your last comment

Comment: This worked for u? If yes then pls accept the answer.

Comment: @AshishGarg based on your solution, during edit - if there is any file present previously which I want to change - cannot possible. because the file upload field will not show in this case